# The computer didn't automatically boot from USB,

Tags: boot

I am new in Ubuntu and created a bootable USB disk first and restarted the PC(with OS Windows8) as recommended in the tutorial. However, the computer didn't automatically boot from USB, no menu box appeared on screen to choose "Try Ubuntu" or "Install Ubuntu", even though I tried holding esc, F12, F10. I appreciate any help!

Comment: What brand/model system. Correct key for UEFI changes and key for one time boot varies by brand. Also if fast boot on in UEFI, you may not have time to press any key. You then can try cold boot or full power shutdown, if laptop remove battery, and hold power switch for 10 seconds or so to drain any left over power. Then boot & immediately press correct key. While in Windows make sure fast start up is also off. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: I disabled fast boot menu, restarted with the bootable USB disk plugged in and it worked ! I have the Ubuntu start page on the screen now! Holding F12 button was not needed! The current problem I am facing now is that there is only "Install Ubuntu" option and no "Try Ubuntu without installing" option. Since I do not want to use Ubuntu as the stand-alone OS, I have to have "Try Ubuntu without installing" option on the display. I appreciate any further help!

Comment: Did you intend to downvote the other answer and accidentally unaccept my answer? Just curious.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you **change**d your **boot priority** in the **BIOS**? I think you can find the settings you want by changing the priority in the BIOS.

Comment: Yes and it worked, but I don't see "Try Ubuntu without installing" option on the start page, which is a new problem for me to overcome!

Comment: The question didn't ask for "without installation".

Answer (score 3):

This article has detailed steps for creating Ubuntu 18.04 Live USB and booting it:

- https://linuxconfig.org/install-ubuntu-from-usb-18-04-bionic-beaver

The part you are stuck on now is getting BIOS to boot the Live USB:

### Access Boot Menu

To access Boot Menu on your computer you will need to hit different keys (or combination of keys) depending on your computer type. Here is the list of possible keys you may have to press depending on your PC:

| Device | Key Combination | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Acer | Esc, F12 or F9 | F12 key most likely |
| Apple | ⌥ | the key is also known as Option or Alt |
| Asus | F8 or Esc |  |
| Compaq | Esc or F9 |  |
| Dell | F12 |  |
| eMachines | F12 |  |
| Fujitsu | F12 |  |
| HP | Esc or F9 |  |
| Lenovo | F8, F10 or F12 | Other possibilities: Novo button or Fn + F11 |
| Samsung | Esc or F2 or F12 | For ultrabooks from Samsung disable the fast boot option in BIOS/UEFI. See next section. |
| VAIO | Esc, F10 or F11 | Other possibilities: Assist button |
| Toshiba | F12 |  |

These are the keys to override the boot priority for a single session. There are other keys for accessing the full BIOS/UEFI menus below.

---

### Access BIOS/UEFI

To access BIOS/UEFI on your computer you will also need to hit different keys (or combination of keys) depending on your computer type. Here is the list of possible keys you may have to press depending on your PC:

<sub>*Key combinations for accessing BIOS/UEFI Device*</sub>

| Device | Key Combination | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Acer | Del or F2 | F2 key most likely |
| Asus | Delet or Del |  |
| Compaq | F10 |  |
| Dell | F2 |  |
| eMachines | Tab or Del |  |
| Fujitsu | F2 |  |
| HP | Esc, F10, F11 | Other possibilities: on Pavilion - F1 |
| Lenovo | F1 or F2 | Other possibilities: small button next to the Power button (if laptop) |
| Samsung | F2 | For ultrabooks from Samsung if might be F10 |
| VAIO | F1, F2, F3 | Other possibilities: Assist button |
| Toshiba | F1, F2, F12 or Esc |  |

Comment: I disabled fast boot menu, restarted with the bootable USB disk plugged in and it worked ! I have the Ubuntu start page on the screen now! Holding F12 button was not needed! The current problem I am facing now is that there is only "Install Ubuntu" option and no "Try Ubuntu without installing" option. Since I do not want to use Ubuntu as the stand-alone OS, I have to have "Try Ubuntu without installing" option on the display. I appreciate any further help!

Comment: You can also [install Ubuntu to a 32GB or 64GB USB](https://www.fosslinux.com/10212/how-to-install-a-complete-ubuntu-on-a-usb-flash-drive.htm). This way it stays off your hard drive and allows you to save changes between boots.