# Windows 10 won't boot anymore after updating from ubuntu 19.04 to 19.10

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

I updated from ubuntu 19.04 to 19.10 yesterday and Windows 10 won't boot anymore from Grub menu. It worked fine before.

For now I can boot to windows by changing the priorities in the bios to windows bootloader but I prefer to have a better solution. I went through the solutions proposed in this post: [*Grub* Windows 10 doesn't start anymore](https://askubuntu.com/questions/725290/grub-windows-10-doesnt-start-anymore) but none of them worked for me.

Fast boot and secure boost are disabled in the bios. Did anyone have the same problem after updating ?

Comment: Yes, I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to [install and run boot-repair](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1104855/how-to-make-grub-menu-appear-instead-grub-minimal-bash-like-in-booting/1105737#1105737):

[image: boot-repair menu.png]

Then check the boot-repair report. If the bottom of the report tells you:

> ```
> For example you can boot into Windows, then type the following command in an admin command prompt:
> bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi
> ```

Boot into Windows by changing the BIOS boot order. See the section in link below on ***Access BIOS/UEFI***:

- [The computer didn't automatically boot from USB,](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1180675/the-computer-didnt-automatically-boot-from-usb/1180697#1180697)

After successfully booting into windows via BIOS/UEFI boot order override, open a command prompt as administer and run the `bcedit` command above.

Then reboot back into BIOS/UEFI and reset Ubuntu to top of boot order.

---

Also note boot-repair can create about 7 custom entries to boot Windows and Ubuntu from UEFI. In my experience they won't all work. After you fix the booting issues see this answer:

- [Boot-Repair created too many grub menu entries for Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/938633/boot-repair-created-too-many-grub-menu-entries-for-windows/1022700#1022700)