# Intel Turbo Boost not showing

Tags: cpu, turbo-boost

Even though i have a turbo boost capable cpu, i7 8th gen 8550U turbo boost up to 4.0 GHz.

1. I get this when I ran:`cpuid -1l6 | grep -i turbo`

   ```
   Intel Turbo Boost Technology            = false
   Intel Turbo Boost Max Technology 3.0    = false
   ```
2. When I ran cpupower on terminal: `cpupower frequency-info`

   ```
   analyzing CPU 0:
     driver: intel_pstate
     CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
     CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
     maximum transition latency:  Cannot determine or is not supported.
     hardware limits: 400 MHz - 1.80 GHz
     available cpufreq governors: performance powersave
     current policy: frequency should be within 400 MHz and 1.10 GHz.
                     The governor "powersave" may decide which speed to use
                     within this range.
     current CPU frequency: Unable to call hardware
     current CPU frequency: 800 MHz (asserted by call to kernel)
     boost state support:
       Supported: no
       Active: no
   ```
3. After running `turbostat` I got:

   ```
   turbostat version 19.08.31 - Len Brown <lenb@kernel.org>
   CPUID(0): GenuineIntel 0x16 CPUID levels; 0x80000008 xlevels; family:model:stepping 0x6:8e:a (6:142:10)
   CPUID(1): SSE3 MONITOR - EIST TM2 TSC MSR ACPI-TM HT TM
   CPUID(6): APERF, No-TURBO, DTS, PTM, HWP, HWPnotify, HWPwindow, HWPepp, No-HWPpkg, EPB
   cpu6: MSR_IA32_MISC_ENABLE: 0x4000850089 (TCC EIST MWAIT PREFETCH No-TURBO)
   CPUID(7): SGX
   cpu6: MSR_IA32_FEATURE_CONTROL: 0x00000005 (Locked )
   CPUID(0x15): eax_crystal: 2 ebx_tsc: 166 ecx_crystal_hz: 0
   TSC: 1992 MHz (24000000 Hz * 166 / 2 / 1000000)
   ** CPUID(0x16): base_mhz: 2000 max_mhz: 4000 bus_mhz: 100 **
   cpu6: MSR_MISC_PWR_MGMT: 0x00401cc0 (ENable-EIST_Coordination DISable-EPB DISable-OOB)
   RAPL: 17476 sec. Joule Counter Range, at 15 Watts
   cpu6: MSR_PLATFORM_INFO: 0x4043df1011400
   4 * 100.0 = 400.0 MHz max efficiency frequency
   20 * 100.0 = 2000.0 MHz base frequency
   cpu6: MSR_IA32_POWER_CTL: 0x0024005d (C1E auto-promotion: DISabled)
   cpu6: MSR_TURBO_RATIO_LIMIT: 0x25252828
   ** 37 * 100.0 = 3700.0 MHz max turbo 4 active cores **
   ** 37 * 100.0 = 3700.0 MHz max turbo 3 active cores **
   ** 40 * 100.0 = 4000.0 MHz max turbo 2 active cores **
   ** 40 * 100.0 = 4000.0 MHz max turbo 1 active cores **
   ```

I have tried:

```
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo
1

echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo
0
tee: /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo: Operation not permitted

sudo echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo
0
tee: /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo: Operation not permitted
```

Any help would be massively appreciated. :)

Comment: Maybe your BIOS has a setting to turn off Turbo Boost?

Comment: BIOS doesn't show any settings for Turbo Boost in ubuntu.

Comment: Ubuntu doesn't show many BIOS values. I was talking about BIOS settings in the BIOS which you access when booting by pressing small button next to power button, pressing F2, pressing Escape, etc. depending on machine make and model: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1180675/the-computer-didnt-automatically-boot-from-usb/1180697#1180697