# Kubnutu 20.04.1 LTS Install Fails on USB Drive

Tags: boot, usb, kubuntu

I am trying to install Kubuntu onto a USB drive so that I can boot directly into Kubuntu when booting from a USB drive. I'm using VirtualBox on Windows to boot into the Kubuntu install ISO I downloaded from kubuntu.org/getkubuntu.

I insert the USB drive and it is recognized by VirtualBox, I then select 'Install Kubuntu', choose minimal installation, and then make my selection for the drive layout as shown in the image and  click Install Now.

[image]

The installation proceeds and I can see activity on the USB drive but when installation completes, the drive is empty. When I try to boot using the drive, I select it from the boot menu, but Windows boots anyway.

Comment: For this purpose it is easier to have two USB pendrives - one of them should be a fast USB 3 pendrive (or even better SSD connected via USB). Clone Kubuntu into the slower USB pendrive with a tool, for example Rufus in Windows. 'DD-mode' is cloning. Then unplug, disconnect or otherwise disable the internal drive, and after that boot into the slower USB drive with Kubuntu, and from there install Kubuntu into the faster USB drive. [This link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1278230/completely-universal-ubuntu-installation/1278821#1278821) and links from it can help you.

Comment: I tried booting into a USB drive as you suggested, but I can't disable my system's internal drives (there are 2). The Guided options at the partition selection only work on my system drives. I select the Manual option when the installer asks for the partition details, but I don't know what selections to make (I don't want to format my system drives). I checked my BIOS and there's no way to disable the system drives.

Comment: Thank you - I got it. I physically removed the dries from my laptop and was able to install Kubuntu using the directions in the top comment.

Comment: I'm glad that you found a solution :-)